# KRaft design architecture - Separation of Controllers and Brokers

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

We want to install *Kafka Kraft cluster* on 35 machines ( machines are DELL physical machines - type R760 And OS is Linux RHEL 8.6 version )

Since we are dealing with **Kafka production cluster** , we want to understand what is the best Practice and the right approach to install the machines and configuration

The question about the cluster that we are preparing is about the **controllers**

Do we need to set and install the controllers on **dedicated machines** and not on Kafka machines itself?

for example I gives here **PLAN1** and **PLAN2**

**PLAN1**

We can install 3 controllers on the first 3 Kafka machines ( means both PID's are running on Kafka machine as broker pid and controller pid     [ *pid - Linux process id* ]

kafka1-3 will include `pid` for broker and `pid` for controller

kafka4+ will include only `pid` for broker

[image]

**PLAN2**

We can install 3 controllers on different dedicated machines

35 physical machines for Kafka Kraft service

3 dedicated VM machines for Kafka controllers ( VM machines since from our understanding controllers are not consume so much resources )

[image]

**The second question** , is about how many controllers services we need?

Is it always 3 controllers for *3 Kafka machines* or for *15 Kafka machines* or for *35 Kafka machines* ?